# Delivering web application through a 3rd party website

Tags: web-applications

I am tasked to find an approach where our web application can be delivered as a solution to our clients through their own website.

It would be easy enough if we offered our solution in a standalone installation, but we deliver our functionality as a service.  We want to offer our functionality to our clients but enable them to keep their own brand.  So the idea is don’t let their user leave their website, but they can use our functionality ‘embedded’ somehow.

I am working with two approaches right now.

The obvious/easiest solution is to deliver our functionality through an iframe.  However there are SSL issues that make that less than ideal.  The second approach is to create a JS library our clients can include and invoke.  This library would make calls to our website, and display the returned content on a div somewhere on their page.

Beyond these two approaches, can someone think of others?

Appreciate any input!

Comment: I can't think of anything else that's not server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going with the iframe approach.  One drawback we found is through an iframe IE won't accept cookies in the default configuration, so we had to write our own antiforgery token solution as the MVC version uses cookies.